# How to convert react draft file to any other format such as pdf

Tags: reactjs, plugins, draftjs

What i am basically trying to do is to provide the feature of converting the text written in react-draft.js editor to a pdf/doc format .

**I am using react-draft-wysiwyg editor**

plz help me how can I achieve the same , do mention if any other plugins are available that can help me out

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-pdf-js ?